# jQuery Script not working with appended data

Tags: jquery, delegates

I am doing a web page with infinite scroll which contains block of contents.Each block has a

tag for adding description.This description should contain more/less button with respect to its length.The script is working for the first loaded blocks of contents.My problem is , on scrolling,new blocks are appended in which more/less buttons are not showing.

My html p tag class is "wall_post_para"

My script is

```
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "More";
var lesstext = "Less";

$('.wall_post_para').each(function() 
{
    var content = $(this).html();
    if(content.length > showChar) 
    {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        //alert(c);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
        //alert(h);
        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
         $(this).html(html);
    }

});



 $(".morelink").click(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass("less"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

I tried using delegate but I don't know how to use delegate with .each().Please Help me.

Comment: Search SO for "Event delegation" - there's 100s of SO questions / answers

Comment: Can you please share me link?

Comment: When you scroll down - exactly how do you append new blocks?  That's not included in the question. The code provided "fixes" existing blocks.  Make this a function and call it when you add new ones.

Comment: I append data using ajax.This data contain lot of html contents along with the description p tag.

Comment: You shouldn't need the whole `$(".wall_post_para")` code - just build your html with the 'more' already built in.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate. Change this:

```
$(".morelink").click(function()
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.morelink', function()
```

This will allow any appended `.morelink`'s to use the click handler, as it goes through the document up to each .morelink...

Comment: Hii,the link 'More' / 'Less' is not at all appearing for the description field for appended data. The full description is showing while scrolling down.

Comment: See @mattgl answer, and my comment - this is what you'll need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Stuart's answer solves a part of the problem that will occur as soon as the problem you actually described is solved.
The way I see it, you are running your script that iterates over the paragraphs with class "wall_post_para" only once. Then more of these elements are added to your page. Of course, these are not affected by the code that has run before.
What you need to do: whenever a new paragraph is added to your page, run the code on it that adds the ellipses and the 'more' button. How you do this depends on how the new paragraphs are added. Maybe you want to elaborate on that to get a more specific answer.

Comment: This is in the right direction.  The code that's in your each loop - wrap that up into a function that you can call, and then make sure to call it for each append too.

Comment: I am appending new data through ajax.Now my doubt is, on which point should i call this function if i wrap the codes in it. This is how I append new data to a div  `.done(function(data) {   
$("#wall_Scrollcontent").append(data);
   })`